# iPhone - cocos2d - Animations and C++ class

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to add animations to my game (iPhone app, using cocos2d).

The game was written in C++, and now I want to run it on iPhone, so most of the classes are in c++.

The thing looks like that.
I'm creating CCSprite,CCAction in obj-c class in init function, and then run CCAction on sprite.
And animation is working.

But I want to put this CCSprite and CCAction variables in my C++ class.
 I create *CCSprite in init class and send this pointer to the c++ class. Then, I create CCAction and run it on the sprite.

And after that, when in my init function (obj-c class) do:

```
return self;
```

then the app is running, running and running and nothing happens. I receive only this message in console:

> *** Assertion failure in -[CCSprite setTexture:], /Users/Michal/..../libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:898
>   Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.

I dont know what should I do next...
Is it possible to keep CCSprite/Action etc. in C++ class succesfully?

Comment: Look at the setTexture method and look for the NSAssert(). It will give you some clues to find what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have properly initialized the texture before you try to use it like this:

```
CCTexture2D *redButtonNormal = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"RedButtonNormal.png"];
```

then initalize the sprite (or sprite subclass - in this example spuButton is a subclass of CCSprite) :

```
spuButton *redButton = [spuButton spuButtonWithTexture:redButtonNormal];
```

Note: since it is a subclass i had to setup the init methods for it like this (You must do this if you subclass CCSprite):

```
+ (id)spuButtonWithTexture:(CCTexture2D *)normalTexture
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithTexture:normalTexture] autorelease];
}

- (id)initWithTexture:(CCTexture2D *)aTexture
{
    if ((self = [super initWithTexture:aTexture]) ) {

        state = kButtonStateNotPressed;
    }

    return self;
}
```